# Windows 8 App Update giving me 0x80246007 errors

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-8-apps

To save disk-space on my C drive (and because I couldn't find an Uninstall function in the Windows Store app), I deleted some apps I never use, from:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

However, now when I try to update apps that I do use, such as:

> Mail, Calendar, People and Messaging

I receive a `0x80246007` error.

#### Troubleshooting

I have tried running this batch script (as admin), but it had no affect:

```
net stop wuauserv
cd %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
ren Download Download.old
net start wuauserv
net stop bits
net start bits
WSReset
```

I also tried using the freeware 'Recuva' application to recover lost files that were Shift-Deleted in that folder; but it gave me ~35,000 files, and wouldn't automatically put them in their respective folders.

---

What do I need to do in order to get the Windows 8 apps I want, working and updateable?

Comment: Impossible. See: http://meta.superuser.com/q/6338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command (unlike `sfc /scannow`) fixed my Store, allowing me to right-click 'Mail' and uninstall that whole suite, then reinstallation got it all working properly =)

> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth